# Inserting two arrays into ListView in Android

Tags: android

I have two arrays

```
arr1:
1 2 3 4 5 6

arr2:
a b c d e f
```

I have custom ListView that has TextView1 and TextView2

How to bind the two arrays into the custom ListView?

```
TextView1  |  TextView2
-----------------------
     1     |      a
     2     |      b
     3     |      c
     4     |      d
     5     |      e
     6     |      f
```

Comment: which problem are you facing here..?

Comment: You'll have to implements a custom `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: please send me your list xml and adapter class.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of two string arrays use Custom Object Array which contains two strings. And make a `custom adapter` and set it to your `listview`. Also make a `Listitem` with two `textview` for like **two column listview**. And set values in your custom adapter's `getView()`.

Look at this tutorial [Android – Multi Column ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/)

[Android – Multi Column ListView](http://sochinda.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/android-multi-column-listview/)